# A series of rileys

Tags: riddle

Riddle 1:

> I’m a colour, but,
> Come hell or my prefix,
> I don’t care mon ami,
>
> My suffix, though is literally nothing.
> My infix is like Higgs, but royalty,
>
> Take my fourth

First Letter:

> E

Riddle 2:

> My middle and start together,
> Are a participle of a verb of wearing,
> But my middle and end, is a bit of medicine,
>
> My infix, is wasted time,
> But my whole, means like a tree.
>
> Take my fifth

First letter:

> C

Riddle 3:

> My prefix is I,
> My suffix is a month,
> My infix is a health tonic,
>
> But I am boring and dry,
> And naive, at that too,
>
> Take my fifth

Riddle 4:

> I’m slow, unmoving, I prefer to stay still,
> And my prefix is your rank in the economy,
> My suffix is the end of an explosive projectile.
>
> My infix are the men at arms,
> But my whole describes plants
>
> Take my seventh

First Letter:

> S

Now what have you got?

Comment: Just to be certain, each riddle has a different riley?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, Each riddle has its own prefix, infix, and suffix. They are not all the same?

Comment: Oh yes, they are all different words

Comment: some hints would be helpful, nice riddle, seems a bit tough to me.

Comment: @Shahriar Mahmud Sajid Hmmm okay, I think I’ll add some

Answer (score 5):

**Partial answer**

**Puzzle 3**

> Jejune

My prefix is I,

> **Je** is *I*, in French.

My suffix is a month,

> **June**

My infix is a health tonic,

> [**Jun**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jun_(drink))

But I am boring and dry,
And naive, at that too,

> Jejune means both *boring and dry* and *naive and simplistic*

Take my fifth

> N

Comment: Correct! But can you solve the others?

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer after the first letters were given:

**Riddle 2**

> **cladose** (fifth letter: O)
>
>  *My middle and start together,
>
>  Are a participle of a verb of wearing,*
>      — **clad** is an old past participle of clothe, still present in compounds such as ironclad.
>  *But my middle and end, is a bit of medicine,*
>      — **a dose** is a quantity of medicine to be administred
>  *My infix, is wasted time,*
>      — **ado** is a fuss about trifles
>  *But my whole, means like a tree.*
>      — **cladose** means having branches

**Riddle 4**

> **sessile** (seventh letter: E)
>
>  *I'm slow, unmoving, I prefer to stay still,*
>      — **sessile** describes immobile organisms
>  *And my prefix is your rank in the economy,*
>      — **SES** is an abbreviation for the socio-economic status
>  *My suffix is the end of an explosive projectile.*
>      — **–ssile** is the end of missile
>  *My infix are the men at arms,*
>      — the **SS** were the Nazi Party's men at arms
>  *But my whole describes plants*
>      — **sessile** can also describe plants without a stem or stalk

Comment: Correct! Well done! Also, I was thinking about adding an o to your wasted time answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Puzzle 1**

> Eerie black

*I’m a colour, but,*

> Eerie black is a color

*Come hell or my prefix,*

> The phrase is "come hell or high water". According to Wiktionary, "ee" is a noun meaning "water" in the language Tukudede.

*I don’t care mon ami,*

*My suffix, though is literally nothing.*

> If you have nothing of something, you have a "lack" of it.

*My infix is like Higgs, but royalty,*

> Peter Higgs, physicist, lives in Edinburgh, Scotland, UK. Something "royal" in Edinburgh is the Royal Infirmary of Edinburgh, or the "RIE"

Take my fourth

> I

**Full puzzle**

So, taking [@M Oehm's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/71867/63153) and [@hexomino's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/71640/63153) into account, we have:

> I O N E

I guess, after solving all those riddles, we were only left with

> ONE I (one eye)

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer: Riddle 2**

> ARBOREAL?

*My middle and start together,*
*Are a participle of a verb of wearing,*

> This is the part I can't figure out.

*But my middle and end, is a bit of medicine,*

> OREAL isn't *exactly* medicine, but such things are often grouped together ("health and beauty").

*My infix, is wasted time,*

> BORE.

*But my whole, means like a tree.*

> Indeed it does.

*Take my fifth*

> R.

**Musings on Riddle 4**

> I keep thinking this must be SEDENTARY, but I can't really make it fit.

*I’m slow, unmoving, I prefer to stay still,*

> That certainly sounds like "sedentary".

*And my prefix is your rank in the economy,*
*My suffix is the end of an explosive projectile.*

> Dunno about these lines.

*My infix are the men at arms, But my whole describes plants*

> A man at arms could be a SENTRY, which *almost* but not quite fits in "sedentary". And plants are indeed sedentary.

*Take my seventh*

> This would be A, which kind of fits with the preceding R and N.

Comment: Good idea, but you’re not on the right lines